# iOS MVVM how to pass data from child to parent view model

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I am new to MVVM. How should I update the data model in parent view model from child view model?

As an example, suppose I have a `CollectionViewModel` for a Newsfeed page, it keeps an array of `Post` (my date model) and an array of `CollectionCellViewModel` that corresponds to individual posts. Each cell makes network request to listen for new likes. How can I pass this information back to `CollectionViewModel` and update `Post`?

Comment: Use the delegation pattern.

Comment: Does RFP work better?

Comment: Define 'better'. I think for a beginner the delegate pattern would be the first thing to try, see the answer below.

Comment: The view updates the view model.  The view model updates the model.  Other view models receive updates from the model and update their views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You achieve that with multiple ways:

- Delegation pattern:

  ```
  protocol CollectionCellViewModelDelegate {
    func onAction()
  }

  class CollectionCellViewModelDelegate: YourType {
    var delegate: CollectionCellViewModelDelegate?

    /// Your custom action
    func yourCustomAction() {
        delegate?.onAction
    }
  }
  ```

then assign .delegate in your parent class and implement `onAction()` method

- Closures:

  ```
  class CollectionCellViewModelDelegate: YourType {
    var yourAction: (()->())?

    func yourAction(_ completion: (()->())?) {
      yourAction = completion
    }

    /// Your custom action
    func yourCustomAction() {
      yourAction?()
    } 
  }
  ```

then call your closure with following code from parent class:

```
child.yourAction { // do custom stuff }
```